# How to get the pixel coordinates of the edge position after the image is processed by the Canny operator

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, canny-operator

After a picture is processed by Canny, it will get more obvious edge features.How can I find the position coordinates of the topmost, bottommost, rightmost part of the body part?The grabcut algorithm requires a matrix to frame the foreground part, and the coordinates are obtained to determine the rectangle.

I need to separate the images and extract the foreground, but the grabcut algorithm needs to manually enter the coordinates of the rectangle. The coordinates of the rectangle are such (x, y, w, x), x and y are the coordinates of the upper left corner of the foreground, w is wide, h is high

I tried to get the coordinates by clicking with the mouse, but this is too inefficient.

[I painted it on the edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oumja.jpg)

[The two points pointed by the arrow need to be ignored because they are not part of the body (in most cases, only a small part of a picture after canny processing does not belong to the subject, or all are subjects)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkWSR.jpg)

Comment: There are too many possible answers to your question. You should also post code to show what you have tried or details of the attempts you have made.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might work is :-

1. Make a copy of the edge information.
2. Add lots and lots and lots of blur
3. Dilate X a large number of times e.g. 30
4. Threshold the image
5. Contract a large number of times e.g. 35
6. Despeckle/Denoise the image
7. Use the result as a template for the original.

Might work. Or maybe use the blob detector https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/